# GCE external IP not from selected region?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I selected my VM zone to be in asia-east1-b but the static I got from generating is from the US? Does google give a IP from the selected region at all?

Comment: IPv4 I assume? They've run out of IPv4 addresses in some regions, not but not all.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for a IPv4 address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the service you're using to check the physical location of the IP address is checking the location of the IP's owner, Google, rather than the IP itself. In any case, the location of the IP isn't really important as long as the routes work properly.